# When should I query from a database in my view, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Problem:**

If I have a scenario where I don't want to change my model properties and need to get one more attribute from some table, is it fine if I write a query inside a view and show the result?

If the answer is no, I would like to know why it's not considered a good way.

Comment: Why not query in the controller and put the data in `ViewBag`, or `ViewData`. Because regarding MVC principle you must separate concern of the View, Model and the Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

View is not a mirror of your data structure. Actually, often it's an
aggregation and/or manipulation for user-friendly *presentation* of the data that stands behind.

Comment: But shouldn't all the data stand behind then ? Meaning that if you change your datamodel, you should adapt your model accordingly ? Innocent question, still discovering MVC myself... but putting database queries in a view seems in contradiction to the MVC principles... no ?

Comment: You change Model to meet data changes, but you may not change a View. And vice versa. I can change View of the data, for newer UI, new control introduced, new set of screens has to be supported...etc, but the data remains the same.

Comment: but there is some scenario where i want to check some condition based on db result that this particular element to be rendered or not, then what should be done?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: there are no rigid rules on this. you can do it in view, or in controller. it depends on who is processing the data in your architecture.

Comment: @Tigran : understood, but then the answer to OP's question should be NO, I think. If I understand well, he wants to get a data from the database that is not yet in his model, and doesn't want to add it in the model so he would like to make a query directly in the view, which is not OK from where I see it... but good to know that the best-practices are not that strict. I already questionned myself about this when adding a data in the model which is only usefull to the view (e.g : "ShowItem")

Comment: @Bartdude: again, it depends. If he has a constrain of not changing a model to meet new requirements, for some reason. View may become a suitable layer, were you if/else data and send to client html based on some condition

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion you should never do that. Just because you loose the entire paradigm of the tool you are using.

In a few years, this is confusing to you, or someone else maintaining the code. If you don't want to change it all, use `dynamic` properties, `ViewBag` or other options to keep your flexibility, test-ability, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should never do queries in your `Views`. It's called *MVC* and the proper way of using it is to separate concepts.

You should have a `Model`, a `Controller`, a `View` and a `Repository` (as the simpliest approach). As the name suggests, `View` must be used only for displaying processed data.

More information about MVC best practices [is here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices#view).

I remember when I started working with MVC. I didn't know about this and my teamleader told me it's never a good choice to do this.

**Conclusion:**

It's just a matter of design and perspective. If you're doing a project for yourself or for the university, organize your code as you wish. If you're working in a professional environment you should respect some working principles

Another important factor to think of, is this: if another person must refactor or modify your code he must know where to find methods, where to find models and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the answer ( fixed some grammar problems :) )

Comment: i accepted @Tigran answer as he answered good in a single sentence. but yoyrs was also good one thats why i voted up..:)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the reason why it's called MVC is because of the separation of concerns. View's are only concerned of the User-Interface. Queries are done on the controller. Another is it would be too confusing if you would place everything in a single page which already defeats the purpose of having MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are cases when querying the database from a View may seem easier and appropriate, you should be ready for the consequences of breaking [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (SoC). When you spread your [DAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) across many layers it's going to be hard to re-factor the database in the future. Another question is security - if you decide to implement database security or controller-based security later, your view-based queries will be a security point.

However, if the project is small, I would trade SoC for performance.